# How can I do multiple chained operations in java-8?

Tags: java, java-8, mongo-java-driver

I have a use case as below.

1. `List<Document>` from mongo
2. For each `Document`

   1. Get a field
   2. Add to a set
   3. Alter the field
   4. Check altered field against two other sets

      1. If not present convert to a pojo
      2. add pojo to a list

I have something as below.

```
Optional.ofNullable(documentList).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).forEach(doc -> {
      // I am doing all the operations in java7 way
})
```

I thought something similar as below.

1. Iterate document list - add field to the set
2. Iterate the set from step1 - check `field` not contains on two other collections - then form pojo from original document - add pojo to list

But here I need to iterate twice. Moreover I need to maintain my original doc also. If my list is huge, iteration time is added unnecessarily.

How can I do this in standard way?

```
documentList.forEach(doc -> {
          String deviceId = doc.getString("deviceId");
          deviceSet.add(deviceId);
          String alteredId = "IMEI" + deviceId;
          if(!clearedDevices.contains(alteredId) && !superSetDevices.contains(deviceId)) {
             //Pojo from Document
             //add pojo to a list
         }
    })
```

Comment: It would help if you can show your code, even if it is the "java7 way". then we can easily convert it.

Comment: @Zabuza Added my current version which I modified from java-7 way

Comment: The “standard way” is `if(documentList != null) for(Document doc: documentList) …`.

Comment: @Holger Then java-8 features are not recommended with my scenario. is it?

Comment: @Gibbs it depends... It can fit very well to J8 depending on types. Is Document a standard java class? Are fields mutables objects? How to get fields? Please precise...

Comment: There’s no reason to rewrite existing code when it provides no benefit. The `Optional` type was introduced to allow to declare *return types* which can be absent, which provides clarity compared to return types which might be `null`, which is not obvious. There is no reason to rewrite simple `if` statements to a more verbose construct. If you want to improve the code, eliminate the possibility for the collection to ever be `null`. The `forEach` method is an option for new code when the action is straight-forward or for a refactoring when the benefit is obvious. Not for rewriting every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on the type of the concerned field. If it is a mutable object, then Java 8 stream is perfect. Something like:

```
documentList.stream()
            .map(d->d.getString("deviceId") // stream of Stringified field
            .peek(deviceSet::add)           // add field to set
            .map("IMEI"::concat)            // alter the field
            .filter(mf->!clearedDevices.contains(mf)&&!superSetDevices.contains(mf)) // filter...
            .map(f->XXX.convert2Pojo(f))    // convert to pojo
            .forEach(pojoList::add)         // add to pojolist, or collect?
```

Comment: `Document` is of `org.bson.Document`. It's mongo db one. Fields are from `Document`.

Comment: This usage of Stream API is wrong. You should never modify another collection through streams.

Comment: @Nikolas Who said so? It is not strictly forbidden (J8 functional is not pure) while I can admit it may be dangerous. But there is many case where that is very useful.

Comment: @Gibbs Oh I misread the provided code, need to rewrite mine...

Comment: This is somewhat of a misuse of peek. "*This method exists mainly to support debugging*" [from docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: @Michael *mainly* not *only*, and whatever this method was created for, it supports any  `Consumer` and I provided one and that usage is of no harm (except in case of multithreaded context). And you may consider that accumulating elements in a set is much like accumulating the elements to some output.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, thanks for that, but I had actually already read it. It's not designed as a general purpose perform-a-side-effect step, because short-circuiting operations would mean it won't work as one might naively expect. If you want to look at it from a more philosophical perspective, side effects also shouldn't be part of a functional approach. Your response to that might be "who cares, as long as it works" which is fine but remember you are advocating this solution to someone who doesn't understand it as well as you, and they deserve to be made aware of that decision as well

Comment: @Michael alas J8 functional (as I said in another comment) is not pure, then you can use side effects. I would not recommend that in general but you can why not use it when it is useful. Using it here leads to a more concises/simple solution; if not either you break the stream into picees, or use internal objects to convey data...